# Incorrect PHP calculation

Tags: php, decimal, modulo, calculation

Can someone give me an explanation on why this is happening in PHP:

```
echo (0.29*100)%100  // result 28
```

It's probably very simple but logically I do not see any explanation. Probably how PHP works in the background.

I was trying to get the first two decimal positions of a number when I ran into this case. Result should be 29 naturally.

If I round the multiplication the result is fine:

```
echo (round(0.29*100))%100  // result 29
```

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator, not division, but it is still curious

Comment: .29 may incur floating point error.  to round, you can add an extra 0.5 after multiplication.

Comment: @aynber, I do know that. The purpose is to extract the 29 from 0.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run that code

```
echo (0.29*100)%100;
```

in in PHP8.1.1 the error message gives you a clue

> PHP 8.1.1
>
> Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 28.999999999999996 to int loses precision in D:\PHP-SOURCE\Testing\tst.php on line 14
>
> Call Stack:
> 0.0001     393688   1. {main}() D:\PHP-SOURCE\Testing\tst.php:0
>
> 28

Comment: hmmm, so this simple multiplication creates that long float number. Why does PHP do that?

Comment: Wait for it .... [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)